# How to start the session timeout after click of an event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me how can i start the session timeout after click of Login Button.
In my case the moment i run the application and go to Login page the session timeout is getting started but in my case i need to start the session timeout once click of Login Button in LogOn Screen.

and one more thing related to above issue the moment session expires and it redirects me to Login Screen(that is fine) but it makes me to enter Login Credentials twice and once i enter the credentials second time then it takes me to further pages.

Awaiting for your response. Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any further information related to this...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your information session timeout will reset automatically after every event performed by the user, so you should not be worried about that, when user click on login button it will reset the session timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes i agree that session timeout resets on any postback...but my question is can i initiate the session timeout after click of Login Button on Logon Screen instead of session timeout initiating at application start up.

Comment: If you have sessions enabled, they will be created for any call to a MVC web page. Can you explain why this is a problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the `Session` timeout. `Session` always initiates at your application's startup but the `Session` timeout resets on any postback or any request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Session would appear to be the wrong thing for what you are trying to achieve. Either a custom timer object embedded in the session would work, or forms auth tickets which would start when you logged in.

Simon